# MongoDB query to compute percentage

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, percentage

I am new to MongoDB and kind of stuck at this query. Any help/guidance will be highly appreciated. I am not able to calculate the percentage in the desired way. There is something wrong with my pipeline where prerequisites of percentage are not computed correctly. Following I provide my unsuccessful attempt along with the desired output.

**Single entry in the collection looks like below:**

```
_id : ObjectId("602fb382f060fff5419fd0d1")
time : "2019/05/02 00:00:00"
station_id : 3544
station_name : "Underhill Ave &; Pacific St"
station_status : "In Service"
latitude : 40.6804836
longitude : -73.9646795
zipcode : 11238
borough : "Brooklyn"
neighbourhood : "Prospect Heights"
available_bikes : 5
available_docks : 21
```

**The query I am trying to solve is:**

```
Given a station_id (e.g., 522) and a num_hours (e.g., 3) passed as parameters:

 - Consider only the measurements where the station_status = “In Service”. 
 - Consider only the measurements for that concrete
   “station_id”. 
 - Compute the percentage of measurements with
   available_bikes = 0 for each hour of the day (e.g., for the period
   [8am, 9am) the percentage is 15.06% and for the period [9am, 10am)
   the percentage is
   27.32%). 
 - Sort the percentage results in decreasing order. 
 - Return the top “num_hours” documents.
```

**The desired output is:**

```
--- DOCUMENT 0 INFO ---
---------------------------------
hour : 19
percentage : 65.37
total_measurements : 283
zero_bikes_measurements : 185
---------------------------------
--- DOCUMENT 1 INFO ---
---------------------------------
hour : 21
percentage : 64.79
total_measurements : 284
zero_bikes_measurements : 184
---------------------------------
--- DOCUMENT 2 INFO ---
---------------------------------
hour : 00
percentage : 63.73
total_measurements : 284
zero_bikes_measurements : 181
```

**My attempt is:**

```
 command_1 = {"$match": {"station_status": "In Service", "station_id": station_id, "available_bikes": 0}}
    my_query.append(command_1)

    command_2 = {"$group": {"_id": "null", "total_measurements": {"$sum": 1}}}
    my_query.append(command_2)  

    command_3 = {"$project": {"_id": 0,
                              "station_id": 1,
                              "station_status": 1,
                              "hour": {"$substr": ["$time", 11, 2]},
                              "available_bikes": 1,
                              "total_measurements": {"$sum": 1}
                              }
                 }
    my_query.append(command_3)

    command_4 = {"$group": {"_id": "$hour", "zero_bikes_measurements": {"$sum": 1}}}
    my_query.append(command_4)

    command_5 = {"$project": {"percent": {
                                  "$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$total_measurements", "$zero_bikes_measurements"]},
                                                100]}}}

    my_query.append(command_5)
```

Comment: It's unlikely you will get much help here unless you make your question a lot clearer, trim out the unncessary stuff, provide some sample data, and make it clear why you don't think your query is working.

Comment: @BellyBuster Thank you for the suggestion. I have added more details about the collection and query.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at this and I'm going to offer some sincere advice:

Don't try and do this in an aggregate query. Just go back to basics and pull the numbers out using `find()`s and then calculate the numbers in python.

If you want to persist with an aggregate query, I will say that your match command filters on `available_bikes` equal to zero. You never have the total number of measurements, so you can never find the percentage. Also when you have done your first `$group`, your "lose" your projection so at that point in the pipeline you only have `total_measurements` and that's it (comment out the commands 3 to 5 to see what I mean).